# Can I understand 'promise/await' model in this way?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a c/c++ developer with rich experience of 'async io/event loop/coroutine'.
Now I am learning node.js from zero, and feel somehow confused on the 'promise/await' model.
Would you  please correct me if I am wrong in this experiment?

I prepare a  script named 'sleep_then_say_sth' which costs 3 seconds to run.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello"
sleep 3 
echo "world"
```

I use the bash script to create some 'aync job' in my node.js playground.

```js
'use strict';

const js_util = require('util');
const {spawn, exec} = require('child_process');
const p_exec = js_util.promisify( exec );


async function exec_some_cmd(cmd) 
{ 
    try {
        let { stdout, stderr } = await p_exec( cmd);
        console.log('stdout:', stdout);
        console.error('stderr:', stderr);

        return 1;

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        console.log( ':(');
    
        return 0;
    }
}

function main() {
    try {
        exec_some_cmd("./sleep_then_say_sth");
        exec_some_cmd("./sleep_then_say_sth");

        console.log("let's write something while waiting.");

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};

main();
```

Now I verify my scripts.

```
$ time node async.js                   <== my test command
let's write something while waiting.   <== this line comes right after I fire the command.
stdout: hello                          <== all other lines comes after about 3 seconds.
world

stderr:
stdout: hello
world

stderr:

real    0m3.058s
user    0m0.049s
sys 0m0.018s
```

Here is my interpretation:
There had been 3 'coroutine thread's,
one is 'main', and one for each 'bash cmd'.

When I saw 【let's write something while waiting. 】The 'main coroutine' ended.
and each 'bash coroutines' costed 3 seconds, they ran parallely, so the 'test cmd' also lasted 3 seconds.

I didn't see any output until test cmd ended, because 'child_process.exec' buffered output of extern command.

When I call 'child_process.exec', a 'coroutine thread' was created;
the 'await' statement actaully 'wait and join's the 'coroutine thread'.

If I write Promise directly, there also would be 'coroutine' created/joined, but howabout the lifecycle?

```js
function do_something_promise_style(){
    function do_something_with_cb(resolve_cb, reject_cb)
    {

        let r = exec_some_cmd("./sleep_then_say_sth");
        if ( r ) {
            console.log("let's call 'resolve'");  // I saw this line and 'Stuff worked!' before my 'bash script' ended.
            resolve_cb("Stuff worked!");          // I want to wait 'bash script' ending, and call 'resolve_cb' or 'reject_cb' depend on the process exit code, how can I do this?
        }
        else {
            console.log("let's call 'reject'");
            reject_cb(Error("It broke"));
        }
    }

    let promise1 = new Promise( do_something_with_cb );  // when we 'new' Promise, do we get 'new coroutine' created ? 
    let promise2 = new Promise( do_something_with_cb );  

    function on_ok(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    }

    function on_ng(e){
        console.log(`Oops, ${e}`);
    }

    promise1.then(on_ok, on_ng);  // when we 'then' a Promise, are we actually 'join'ing the coroutine? 
    promise2.then(on_ok, on_ng);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: node.js is mono thread and it uses the event loop to handle asynchronous code. take a look here https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call an `async function` without `await`, it basically creates a "task" (that will only resolve later) then *continues* to with the following statements.
So your first version of main() is basically:

```
function main() {
    try {
        exec_some_cmd("./sleep_then_say_sth"); //creates a task, then continues with the next statement
        exec_some_cmd("./sleep_then_say_sth"); //same as above; it may start executing before the previous one finishes
/* note that since you don't use 'await', main() will keep going, and 
   the main function can exit before any error can be thrown from within the exec_some_cmd calls. 
   Even if it happens while main is still unfinished, it won't be caught unless you can await*/
        console.log("let's write something while waiting.");

    } catch (error) { //not designed to catch errors from non-awaited Promises, so you'll not catch anything here
        console.error(error);
    }
};
```

What you probably want is something like this (two promises in parallel):

```
async function main(){
    try {
        let promise1 = exec_some_cmd("./sleep_then_say_sth");
        let promise2 = exec_some_cmd("./sleep_then_say_sth");

        console.log("let's write something while waiting.");
        await Promise.all( [promise1, promise2] );
        console.log("Both promises are resolved");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

or (sequentially, i.e. wait for one promise to resolve before creating another one)

```
async function main(){
    try {
        await exec_some_cmd("./sleep_then_say_sth");
        console.log("First promise resolved, creating another one");
        await exec_some_cmd("./sleep_then_say_sth");

        console.log("Both promises are resolved");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

(note that in order to use `await`, I used `async function` above instead of just `function`)

And for your second JS code:
Note that a function declared as `async function` will always return a Promise object, so even though you wrote `return 1` and `return 0`, instead of actually returning a number, it will return a `Promise` that can be 'unwrapped' to get a number (TypeScript notation: `Promise<number>`).
Therefore your inner function operates more or less like this:

```
    function do_something_with_cb(resolve_cb, reject_cb)
    {

        let r = exec_some_cmd("./sleep_then_say_sth"); //the value of 'r' is now a Promise object
        if ( r ) { //when you convert a JS object to boolean, you'll get true
            console.log("let's call 'resolve'");  
            resolve_cb("Stuff worked!"); //this is always reached        
        }
        else { //it will never get here!
            console.log("let's call 'reject'");
            reject_cb(Error("It broke"));
        }
    }
```

You need to use `await` to "unwrap" the result of the Promise, and `await` is only available in functions declared as `async function`.

```
    async function do_something_with_cb(resolve_cb, reject_cb)
    {

        let r = await exec_some_cmd("./sleep_then_say_sth"); //the value of 'r' here is either 0 or 1
        if ( r ) { 
            console.log("let's call 'resolve'");  
            resolve_cb("Stuff worked!");
        }
        else { //now it is possible to get here
            console.log("let's call 'reject'");
            reject_cb(Error("It broke"));
        }
    }
```

For `then` called with one function as its argument, it's basically, use the "unwrapped" value of Promise in another function. If there is a second function passed, it will use the Error in that second function.
In your example, `on_ok` will receive `"Stuff worked!"` as its argument, whereas `on_ng` will receive an Error object (`Error: It broke`) as its argument.

I'm not sure what you mean by "joining", but `on_ok` will run *after* the Promise is resolved (not "in parallel").
To run something only after two promises resolve, use `Promise.all( [promise1, promise2] )` with either `then` or `await`.

Some other points about promises:

1. In all cases I can think of, `result = await (promise1.then(some_function_1));` is just like `let success_value = await promise1; result = await some_function_1(success_value)`, but without the temporary variable. For example:

```
async function promise_3(){return 3;}
async function some_function_1(number){return number + 1; }

async function test1(){
   let promise1 = promise_3(); 
   let result = await (promise1.then(some_function_1));
   console.log(result) 
}
async function test2(){
   let promise1 = promise_3(); 
   let temp = await promise1;
   let result = await some_function_1(temp); 
   console.log(result) 
}
test1() 
test2()
```

2. non-awaited Promises will not be caught by try...catch block, even if the first function is unfinished when it is thrown:

```
async function second(){
    console.log("About to throw")
    throw new Error("Thrown from second");  
}
async function first(){
    try{
        console.log("About to create task #2")
        second() //note: non-awaited Promise, errors are not caught within first()
        console.log("After creating task #2")
        await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 4000)); 
        console.log("4 seconds after creating task #2")
    }catch(e){
        console.log("Did I catch anything?", e ) //not reached, but if you used 'await second()' instead, this will be reached
    }
}
first();
process.on('unhandledRejection', (e) =>{ console.log("Unhandled Rejection", e) })
```

3. About using forEach with async functions: let me show a 'wrong' example:

```
async function outer() {
    let input = [3, 1, 2];
    let result = await input.forEach(async (num) => {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, num * 1000));
        console.log("I waited for " + num + " s");
        return num * 2;
    });
    console.log("The result I waited for:", result)
}

outer();
```

"The result I waited for: undefined" will appear, followed by 'I waited for 1 s', 'I waited for 2 s' , 'I waited for 3 s'
Refactoring the argument of forEach into a separate function makes it much clearer why:

```
async function foo(num) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, num * 1000)); //it should now be clear that this 'await' is for the foo, and not for the 'outer' function
    console.log("I waited for " + num + " s");
    return num * 2; //this 'return' won't affect the outer function either!
}
async function outer() {
    let input = [3, 1, 2];
    let result = await input.forEach(foo); //forEach always returns 'undefined', and the 'await' has no effect 
    console.log("The result I waited for:", result)
}
outer();
```

If you don’t care about which iteration finishes the task first, one can use `map` and `await Promise.all`:

```
async function outer() {
    let input = [3, 1, 2];
    let arrayOfPromises = input.map(async (num) => {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, num * 1000));
        console.log("I waited for " + num + " s");
        return num * 2;
    });
    let result = await Promise.all(arrayOfPromises);
    console.log("The result I waited for:", result)
}

outer();
```

Or if you want it to go sequentially (according to the order in the array), one entry waits for another:

```
async function outer() {
    let input = [3, 1, 2];
    let result = [];
    for (let num of input) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, num * 1000));
        console.log("I waited for " + num + " s");
        result.push(num * 2)
    }
    console.log("The result I waited for:", result)
}

outer();
```

Comment: You are so generous, I am clear now, thanks a ton :)

Comment: You’re welcome. I know how JS-style async functions can be confusing to people new to it.
And I thought of another topic that can become confusing: using forEach with Promises. I’ll add a note about it.

Answer (score 1):

Even though in the function exec_some_cmd you await for the execution of the bash scripts, you need to also await in the main function:

```
function main() {
    try {
        await exec_some_cmd("./sleep_then_say_sth");
        await exec_some_cmd("./sleep_then_say_sth");

        console.log("let's write something while waiting.");

    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};
```

Then the output will be:

```
stdout: hello                          
world

stderr:
stdout: hello
world

stderr:
let's write something while waiting.
```

I recomment you look into the event loop to understand it. Good video reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: In order to use `await` in a function, the function should be declared `async function`. So, `async function main(){ ...`